# Android development - Closed alpha testing

Tags: android, testing

I'm new to Android Development and my application right now is on closed Alpha testing. I already uploaded it on Google play, created a list with the email of the testers I want to invite to test my application. What I want to know is: Do I need to publish my application to begin this closed alpha testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link appears when Google accept the app. If you've already uploaded the APK you just wait.

You need to share the opt-in link with your alpha testers once Google accepts it.

Comment: But it says "An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app." so I need to publish the app, right?

Comment: Yes you need to publish it but it would be on alpha version - invisible

Comment: aloupas - How do I publish on the alpha version?

Comment: newhouse - What do I need to do to make google accept my app?

Comment: This is a bit of an act of faith.

Comment: How long does it normally take? I pushed my closed alpha 40 minutes ago. It tested automatically on 10 devices (zero issues) like 30 minutes ago.

Comment: "An opt-in link will be available here when /we/ publish your app."